# How do I download images from Google Keep?

Tags: google-chrome, images, download, google-keep

I shared an image from my phone to Google Keep. I open it on the Google Keep Chrome application. But there's no download option.

How do I download images from Google Keep? Is there a work-around?

Comment: Same problem for me, I think they have yet to add that feature to the Chrome App

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Chrome Application, but you can access your "Keeps" directly by navigating to https://keep.google.com

From there find the note that contains your image...

1. Open the note
2. Click the image (to display just the image)
3. Right mouse and "Save image as..." (in Chrome)

This saved the original (8mp) image for me, not a reduced-for-web version that you might expect using this method.

Comment: Yes this works for me too! Thank you! So I guess you just can't do this from the Chrome application...which I am uninstalling since it's next to useless.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the right click download option in Chrome, but it never get the original image.

I tried to share the image from my Google Keep app via e-mail (use own e-mail address) and successfully got the image with original clarity.